# Is my logic correct for $f \geq 0, $is measurable, and $\int f =0,$ then $f = 0$ a.e.

Tags: measure-theory

Step 1: since $f$ is greater than $0$ and $\int f= 0,\exists$ simple function $h$ such that $0 \leq h \leq f$ on all domain.

Step 2: Let $m(E) \neq 0 $ and $f(x) > 0, \forall x \in E $, then let $\epsilon > 0, s.t. \epsilon < f$ on all E

Step 3. Let the $h = \epsilon,$ on E,$ 0$  on $E^c$, then $\int h = \epsilon m(E) > 0$ and hence a contradiction

Comment: Your step 2 seems not correct: $f>0$ in $E$ does not imply that there exists $\epsilon > 0$ s.t. $f > \epsilon$ in $E$.

Comment: ok, is there any hint available to prove it this way?

Comment: Hint: observe that $\{ x : f(x) \ne 0 \} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{ x : f(x) > 1/n \}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:
for any fixed $\epsilon > 0$, you have
$$
0 = \int_X f \geq \int_{\{f > \epsilon\}} f \geq \epsilon \, m \{f > \epsilon\}.
$$